# Java: PriorityQueue initializations

Tags: java, priority-queue

I am trying to understand the following line which initiates a Priority Queue:

```
PriorityQueue<int[]> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> b[1] - a[1]);
```

Comparing with Constructor section in the document, 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

I couldn't figure out which Constructor it uses. Could someone please share the thought?

Also, is there a document that could better explain/define syntax `(a, b) -> b[1] - a[1]` ... though I could guess what it means.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks like a `Comparator` is being supplied to the queue so that items are added in the correct order. The Java 8 `PriorityQueue` implementation allows that form of the constructor.

Comment: You are looking in the wrong version of javadoc. It's obviously a creature from Java 8.

Comment: Whenever you see a lambda `->`, it requires at least Java 1.8 to compile!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your construction of the `PriorityQueue` uses a constructor that didn't yet exist in 1.7, which is the version of the Javadocs you linked.

It uses a [constructor that takes a `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-) that was added for Java 1.8, which is matched to the lambda expression you supplied.

> Creates a `PriorityQueue` with the default initial capacity and whose elements are ordered according to the specified comparator.
>
> **Since:**
>
> `1.8`

[Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) were introduced with Java 1.8.  Here, basically you have 2 arguments and expression that are matched to a *functional* interface --`Comparator`.

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8, [there's a new constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.Comparator-) that has a `Comparator` for argument:

```
public PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)
```

Thus the initialization using a lambda is valid Java 8+ code.

Answer (score 1):

In Priority Queue you will essentially put user define objects, so to do it priority queue asks you how to order these objects (because priority queues are like heap data structures -- a min/max heap ) so we give it a Comparator which has a compare method ideally denoted by ((a, b) -> b[1] - a[1]) , this method give +ve, -ve or a zero result based on b > a , b < a or b = a. By this result it decides whether it should arrange the elements in ascending or descending order.

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java